# Does function know about the class before binding

Tags: python, methods, metaprogramming, python-descriptors

Is there a way to access a class (where function is defined as a method) before there is an instance of that class?

```py
class MyClass:
    def method(self):
        print("Calling me")

m1 = MyClass.method

instance = MyClass()
m2 = instance.method
print(m2.__self__.__class__)  # <class 'MyClass'>

# how to access `MyClass` from `m1`?
```

For example I have `m1` variable somewhere in my code and want to have a reference to `MyClass` the same way I can access it from bound method `m2.__self__.__class__`.

```py
print(m1.__qualname__)  # 'MyClass.method'
```

The only option I was able to find is `__qualname__` which is a string containing name of the class.

Comment: "The only option I was able to find is `__qualname__` which is a string containing name of the class." that might be one of your better options, although, if the method is added later, e.g. `def foo(self): print("foo")` and `MyClass.baz = foo` I don't think that will be part of the qualified name, so it will not work for that case, but maybe that doesn't matter for what you are doing

Comment: But basically, `MyClass.method` just returns the function object. The function object doesn't keep track of all the places it is referenced, as far as I am aware, so there won't be a direct way like with a bound-method object

Comment: Also note, `m2.__self__.__class__` will give you the type of the instance, which isn't necessarily where the *method is defined*. You *could* walk the mro and check the namespaces for the precise class, though, if inheritance plays into this

Comment: Note that the method comes into existence *before* the class, so there might not even be a class to find. For example, if you want to access the class in a method decorator, you're out of luck, because the decorator executes before the class is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `__self__` itself is annotated by Python when the function is bound to an instance and become a method. (The code to that is run somewhere when running the `__get__` code in the function, but passing an instance different than None).

So, as people pointed out, you have the option of getting the classname as a string by going through `__qualname__`. Otherwise, if the functions/methods for which you will need this feature are known beforehand, it is possible to create a decorator that will annotate their class when they are retrieved as a class attribute (in contrast to the native annotation which only takes place when retrieving then as an instance attribute):

```
class unboundmethod:
    def __init__(self, func, cls):
        self.__func__ = func
        self.class_ = cls
        self.__self__ = None
        
    def __call__(self, instance, *args, **kw):
        if not isinstance(instance, self.class_):
            # This check is actually optional fancy stuff, since we are here! :-)
            raise TypeError(f"First parameter fo {self.__func__.__name__} must be an instance of {self.class_}")
        return self.__func__(instance, *args, **kw)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Unbound method {self.__func__!r} related to {self.class_}"


class clsbind:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            # the function is being retrieved from the class:
            return unboundmethod(self.func, owner)
        # return control to usual method creation codepath:
        return self.func.__get__(instance, owner)
    

class MyClass:
    @clsbind
    def method(self):
        print("Calling me")
```

And on the REPL you can have this:

```
In [136]: m1 = MyClass.method

In [137]: m1.class_
Out[137]: __main__.MyClass

In [138]: m1(MyClass())
Calling me
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class instance using the `__qualname__`

```
    my_class = eval(m1.__qualname__.split('.')[-2])
    print(my_class)
```

Not the most generic and safest approach, but should work for this simple scenario.

Comment: this wouldn't work for cases like `my_function.<locals>.MyClass.method`, so probably `[-2]` is better here